# Function changing the value of argument in Python

Tags: python, debugging, pygame

I am trying to write a program for [Conway's Game of Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life), and I came across some really weird problems, so I'm going step by step and trying to debug it. There is some weird stuff going on.

If you are not familiar with Conway's game of Life, the rules for determining the next stage is simply:

- Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies, as if caused
  by under-population.
- Any live cell with two or three live neighbours lives on to the next
  generation.
- Any live cell with more than three live neighbours dies, as if by
  overcrowding.
- Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell,
  as if by reproduction.

I'm keeping a list called **squareList** that has N_ROWS rows and N_COL columns. I reference each element as **squareList[i][j]**.

My **get_next(squareList)** function returns another list that counts the number of 'neighbors' in each square, and returns another list with the next stage.

Now, onto my problem. Here is a test case that highlights that a function is changing values it is not supposed to:

```
squareList = init_list(NUM_ROWS, NUM_COL) #sets all values in squareList to zero.
                                          #here, NUM_ROWS = 12 and NUM_COL = 18

squareList[11][17] = 1

squareList[5][7] = 1
squareList[6][7] = 1
squareList[7][7] = 1

squareList[9][2] = 1
squareList[9][3] = 1
squareList[9][4] = 1

print_list(squareList)                #prints squareList
nextList = get_next(squareList)       #does NOT change squareList
print '\n--------------------------------------\n'
print_list(squareList)                #prints squareList again

sys.exit()
```

What I get when I use my print_list function is:

[image]

As you can see, everything touched by the get_next function is set to zero. This shouldn't happen in my mind for two reasons:

1. It's not what should happen according to the Conway logic in my get_next function (and I really cannot find why it would not work)
2. **My get_next function is setting a *nextList* variable, it's not supposed to do ANYTHING to *squareList* !!** What am I missing??

Here's the code for my get_next function:

```
def get_next(squareList): #gets the next list for the game of life

  nextList = squareList

  for i in range(1,NUM_ROWS - 1):
    for j in range(1,NUM_COL-1):

      #num of neighbors:
      counter = sum( [squareList[i+x][j+y] for x in range(-1,2) for y in range(-1,2) if not (x==y and x == 0)]) 

      #logic for changing:
      if squareList[i][j] == 1 and counter < 2: nextList[i][j] = 0
      elif squareList[i][j] == 1 and counter > 3: nextList[i][j] = 0
      elif squareList[i][j] == 0 and counter == 3: nextList[i][j] = 1

  return nextList
```

My original thought is that it's changing a global variable, but it's not the case. First, python needs to declare global variables it uses within the function, and second, I tried changing the names of the lists, and got the same results.

EDIT: reply to lanzz suggestion:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you do in your `get_next` function is to make `nextList` a reference to the same list that `squareList` points to. Assignment does not imply copying — `nextList = squareList` makes both names point to the same actual structure in memory, so any change to `nextList` will affect `squareList` as well.

You should use [`copy.deepcopy`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) to obtain an actual copy of your `squareList` list.

Comment: I thought that you couldn't change the values of arguments in python. 
For instance:
a = 3 --- def sum(a,n): a = a + n --- sum(a,3) ----> a = 3, and not a = 6. Is this not also true for lists?

Comment: You're not changing the _value_ of the parameter - the value remains the list you have passed to your function. The _list_ itself, however, is _mutable_ - you can change its contents, and those changes will be visible everywhere you have a reference to the same list.

Comment: I think I got it. However, your suggestion isn't working for me. See above edit. What I want is to copy another list and be able to edit those values without altering the initial one.

Comment: Since you actually have a list of lists, you should use `copy.deepcopy` instead of `copy.copy`